# Linear algebra Matrix-vector multiplication, transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I'm working through problems in "coding the matrix" by Philip N. Klein and there is a problem:

> What 3 x 3 matrix M satisfies M * [x,y,z] = [z+x,y,x] for all vectors [x,y,z]

My is [[1,0,1], [0,1,0], [1,0,0]]
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My reasoning is [1,0,1] take x and z component of the vector and add them together. But this is not correct. Can someone explain why my answer is wrong?

Comment: your reasoning is correct, you have only to fix last row

Comment: my mistake I misread last symbol in z+x,y,x, I though it should be z not x. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: What's the meaning of $M^*$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ops my fault...it's simply a nultiplication symbol!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have done wrong is that , the vectors you have choosen are needed to be written as a column vector not as a row vector.